# What's the most readable way to write nested functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, readability, code-readability

Example this code I wrote doesn't seem as readable as it could be:

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
    return messages.filter((messages) => {
        return messages.message.length < 50
    }).map((object) => {
        return object.message
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems okay to me to be honest. What you could do is replace the "50" with a variable in your js file.

```
var MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH= 50;
```

And re position a bit the way you address the function

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
    return messages
        .filter( (messageObject) => { 
            return messageObject.message.length < MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH 
        })
        .map( (messageObject) => {
            return messageObject.message 
        });
}
```

Also I find that when addressing an array of `messages` and running through the `filter` function, it is better to not call the object `messages` but `item` or `messageObject`

moreover, `object` in the `map` function is a bit ominous, call it `messageObject` again for example so you know what you are using specifically

Answer (score 1):

in ES 6 you can use shortcuts, like this:

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
    return messages.filter( messages => messages.message.length < 50).map( object => object.message )
}
```

Its depend on you which one is readable. In one line you dont need to use `{}` nor `return` and if you use array function, with 1 parameter you also dont need `(messages) =>` , you can use only `messages =>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getShortMessages(messages) {
  return messages.filter(message => message.message.length < 50)
    .map(message => message.message)
}
```